# Functionally is torch.multinomial the same as torch.distributions.categorical.Categorical?

Tags: python, pytorch, distribution, multinomial

For example, if I provide a probability array of [0.5, 0.5], both functions will sample the index [0,1] with equal probability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

> [`torch.distributions.categorical.Categorical()`] is equivalent to the distribution that `torch.multinomial()` samples from.

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#categorical